# Add Adsense on HTTPS page - is this working?

Tags: https, adsense

I know that Google has no HTTPS alternative for their AdSense code and if you decide to embed their HTTP code into your secure page you will get some warnings from the browser. The script they give to you when inserting an ad from them is `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js`.

Now, what I did was changing the `http://` by `https://`, so the warning disappeared (page fully secure), and the ads are displayed correctly. My questions are:
1.) Is this really working? I mean, is this a real HTTPS link or just some trick to fool the browser?
2.) I didn't find that there would exist this HTTPS link (as I said, I just tried to change HTTP to HTTPS and I found out that it works). Is what I am doing legal, secure, recommended?

Thanks!